# How to assign a 2 digit unique id to players

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i am making a multiplayer game using html , node js and socket.io. Initially i was sending socket_id, player positions(x,y) and angle in game updates. As socket id is quite long and uses more bytes , i want to use a small (2 or 3 words/number) id to represent each player in place of socket id. Max a game can have 50 players. If i make id using random numbers(0-100) there are chances that id is already taken by some player(if there are already 30 to 40 players). What could be the better algorithm to assign id.

When a player dies or quit the game, that id is free so that it can be assigned(not necessarily) to new player.

Comment: first player gets 1, second 2, ...

Comment: Just start with 1 and add +1 for every new player?  No need for random.

Comment: This way id value can reach a bigger number when player quits the game.

Comment: you can keep incrementing passed 50.. without random. incrementing is the best way to go

Comment: My example was very basic. Ways to counter your problem are: 1) ignore it. You won't reach `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, ever. 2) store removed ids in an array, and assign values from that array, before assigning a new id.

Comment: @ASDFGerte What do you mean? You can easily pass the max safe integer limit if everyone on the planet, including babies, plays the game an average of 1.125 million times each :D

Comment: Requirement is to have a short id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save all used id's in an array and then check if id is unique:

```
const arrayOfIds = [];

const getRandomBetween1And60 = () => {  

let newNumber = arrayOfIds[0] // just as start value  

while(arrayOfIds.includes(newNumber)) {    
 newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 1  
 }  
 return newNumber; 
}


... 

const newId = getRandomBetween1And60();
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to simply increment:

```
let curId = 0;
//...
player.id = curId;
curId+=1;
```

If you want to make it random, follow this:

1. Make an array of numbers 0..100
2. Pick a random number for the ID from the array
3. Remove it from the array
4. Repeat

---

I would recommend the first approach because the second one limits the number of potential users. Though theoretically, if I had 10,000 known users, I would use the second approach and add the id back to the array when the user disconnected. So I didn't keep incrementing indefinitely.